# Weird Vuex Bug: "Undefined", (When It Shows Defined In The Console)?

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I'm trying to reference a variable in the vuex state object.  The console log shows the variable & value in the object as a whole.  But when I try to reference the specific variable in the object, it shows as "undefined"???

Here's the object from the console output:
[image]

I'm trying to reference state.columnPercentChecked from that object in Vuex actions like so:

```
  checkAndSetColumnPercent (state) {
    console.log('CHECK & SET COLUMN PERCENT ')
    console.log(state.columnPercentChecked)
    console.log(state)
    if (state.columnPercentChecked === true) {
      console.log('checkAndSetColumnPercent TRUE HIT ')
      var colPercent = state.getters('getColumnPercent')
      console.log('checkAndSetColumnPercent : colpercent ' + colPercent)
      state.commit('CHANGE_INITIAL_PERCENT', colPercent)
    }
```

Console log shows the reference to it as "undefined"???  Where am I going wrong here?

Here's the store.js file in full context:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

// root state object.
// each Vuex instance is just a single state tree.
const state = {
    initialPercent: 100,
    columnPercentChecked: false,
    pricePoints: [],
    optimizePrices: false,
    optimizeAbove: null,
    startAsset: null,
    endAsset: null,
    assetPair: null,
    exchange: null
}
// mutations are operations that actually mutates the state.
// each mutation handler gets the entire state tree as the
// first argument, followed by additional payload arguments.
// mutations must be synchronous and can be recorded by plugins
// for debugging purposes.
const mutations = {
  ADD_PRICE_POINT ({pricePoints}, pricePoint) {
    state.pricePoints.push(pricePoint)
  },
  DELETE_PRICE_POINT ({pricePoints}) {
    pricePoints.splice(state.pricePoints, 1)
  },
  CHANGE_INITIAL_PERCENT ({initialPercent}, newPercent) {
    state.initialPercent = newPercent
  },
  TOGGLE_COLUMN_CHECKED ({columnPercentChecked}) {
    state.columnPercentChecked = !columnPercentChecked
  }
}
// actions are functions that causes side effects and can involve
// asynchronous operations.
const actions = {
  addPricePoint (state, pricePoint) {
    state.commit('ADD_PRICE_POINT', pricePoint)
    state.dispatch('checkAndSetColumnPercent')
  },
  changeInitialPercent (state, newPercent) {
    state.commit('CHANGE_INITIAL_PERCENT', newPercent)
    if (state.columnPercentChecked === true ) {
      state.commit('TOGGLE_COLUMN_CHECKED')
    }
  },
  toggleColumnPercentChecked (state) {
    state.commit('TOGGLE_COLUMN_CHECKED')
    state.dispatch('checkAndSetColumnPercent')
  },
  checkAndSetColumnPercent (state) {
    console.log('CHECK & SET COLUMN PERCENT ')
    console.log(state.columnPercentChecked)
    console.log(state)
    if (state.columnPercentChecked === true) {
      console.log('checkAndSetColumnPercent TRUE HIT ')
      var colPercent = state.getters('getColumnPercent')
      console.log('checkAndSetColumnPercent : colpercent ' + colPercent)
      state.commit('CHANGE_INITIAL_PERCENT', colPercent)
    }
  }
}
// getters are functions
const getters = {
  getColumnPercent ({ pricePoints }) {
    var l = pricePoints.length
    if (l > 1){
      return 100 / l
    }
    return 100
  }
}
// A Vuex instance is created by combining the state, mutations, actions,
// and getters.
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations
})
```

Comment: Looks like the object you are logging, `state`, has a `state` property. So, `state.state.columnPercentChecked`. TBH I think you want to deconstruct the state out of the function parameter as in `checkAndSetColumnPercent ({state})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to define your action in this manner:

```
checkAndSetColumnPercent ({state, commit, getters}) {
    console.log('CHECK & SET COLUMN PERCENT ')
    console.log(state.columnPercentChecked)
    console.log(state)
    if (state.columnPercentChecked === true) {
      console.log('checkAndSetColumnPercent TRUE HIT ')
      var colPercent = getters.getColumnPercent
      console.log('checkAndSetColumnPercent : colpercent ' + colPercent)
      commit('CHANGE_INITIAL_PERCENT', colPercent)
    }
}
```

Note the deconstructed `({state})`.

You can see in the [documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/actions.html) that actions are passed a `context` that includes `state`.

**Edit**

Looked like you were using a few more things that come from the `context` so I added them to the deconstruction.

Comment: Any reason it would through "getters is not a function" error?  From what I can tell it should find it too?

Comment: @Emily from your console it shows that `getters` is an object. So possibly you need `getters.getColumnPercent`. Documentation agrees. https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html